# How is "some other pending, unblocked signal" involved when a process sends a signal to itself?

Tags: linux, kill, signals

[Advanced Programming Unix Environment](https://books.google.com/books?id=_kpsAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA338&dq=If%20the%20call%20to%20kill%20causes%20the%20signal%20to%20be%20generated%20for%20the%20calling%20process%20and%20if%20the%20signal%20is%20not%20blocked%2C&pg=PA338#v=onepage&q&f=false) says:

> ```
> #include <signal.h>
> int kill(pid_t pid, int signo);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> If the call to `kill` causes the signal to be generated for the
>   calling process and if the signal is not blocked, either `signo` or
>   **some other pending, unblocked signal** is delivered to  the  process 
>   before kill returns**.  (Additional conditions  occur  with  threads; 
>   see Section 12.8 for more information.)

`kill(pid, signo)` only sends signal `signo`. How is  "some other pending, unblocked signal" involved when a process sends a signal to itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Before the call to `kill` returns, *some* signal is delivered. If there is already a signal waiting to be delivered ("pending") from some other source, it may happen that the signal delivered in between the start of calling `kill` and the end ("before it returns") is that pre-existing signal instead of the one you just made.

If there is no signal already waiting to be delivered, the `signo` signal you specified will be delivered in that interval as you expected.

If there *is* a pending signal, it is unspecified whether it or your new signal is delivered, only guaranteed that at least one of them is.

Comment: Thanks. Reliable signals are not lost. So why "If there is a pending signal, it is unspecified whether it or your new signal is delivered, only guaranteed that at least one of them is", rather than both are delivered?

Comment: Usually because existing systems had differing behaviour.